# glob() fails to return results on Google App Engine, works locally

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zend-framework2, glob

I'm building an app on Zend Framework 2 which will eventually be run on Google App Engine. As it stands, the app runs perfectly locally using App Engine's `dev_appserver.py` command. However, once the app is deployed to App Engine Proper I get a White Screen of Death and the following error in the console:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\Stdlib\Exception\RuntimeException'
    with message
    'glob('module/{*}/config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php', 1024) failed'
```

The default ZF2 glob for `'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'` seems to work fine, as the function returns a result, however `glob('module/{*}/config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php', 1024)` returns false with no visible error messages caught by `Zend\Stdlib\ErrorHandler`.

Has anyone else experienced this error? I suspect it's due to the way GAE stores files once deployed to the system, but I haven't used it enough to know either way.

The relevant part of `application.config.php` is as follows:

```
'module_listener_options' => [
    'config_glob_paths' => [
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        'module/{*}/config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ],
],
```

As mentioned above, it works perfectly when run locally, but fails on the second `glob()` call when run on GAE itself.

Comment: opendir function gaves you the same error?

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: If zend-framework2 had come up in the search when I was entering them, I'd have used it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10623). Star the issue to get updated when it's status changes.

In the meantime, is it possible for you use opendir/readdir? It has the added bonus of apparently being [faster](http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/putting-glob-to-the-test/).

Comment: Cheers. I'll keep an eye on it, and in the meantime re-write the config-loading code to use `open- / readdir()`. Might add it as an option in the global config so that you can choose whether to use glob or manually search the autoload folders.